# Connecting Active Directory to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, active-directory, openldap

I'm facing a problem when connecting my openLDAP Active directory to a WordPress plugin.
I have the correct DN Base and correct ports yet, It seems like it cannot verify the used username to authenticate against the Active Directory.
I tried admin@organization.com which I'm Logged in as: cn=admin,dc=organization,dc=com in openLdap
and I putted the password it didn't work.

Note that I'm using docker Ubuntu openLDAP image

[image: plugin error]
[image: openLDAP error log]

Comment: Active Directory is a very specific LDAP implementation, not necessarily implemented by OpenLDAP. AD allows to bind with user principal name, e.g. `admin@organization.com`, but in general you should bind with DN, i.e. `cn=admin,dc=organization,dc=com`. Still, if the plugin expects anything AD-specific, this may not be available in OpenLDAP.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I used ApacheDS and a different AD WP integration plugin and it worked!